# How to pass value from user control to its parent form?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a user control that will supposedly pass value to its parent form which is form1.

I used the code below.

User Control

```
 public int _control;
 public int control
 {
      get{return _control;}
      set{_control=value;}
 }
```

Form1 assign value to UserControl

```
 UserControl1 uc=new UserControl1();
 uc.control=1;
```

User Control Button_Click

```
 var parent = this.Parent as Form1;
 //MessageBox.Show(_control.ToString());
 parent.userNo=_control;
```

Form1

```
 public int _userNo;
 public int userNo
 {
      get{return _userNo;}
      set{_userNo=value;}
 }
```

The problem is when i used messagebox.show, it will appear displaying 1 but when i used

```
 parent.userNo=_control;
```

it returns a Null Reference Exception.

Please help!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

That means that parent is Null. this is due to the fact that the parent is NOT an instance of the class Form1.

in fact, this cast:

```
this.Parent as Form1
```

returns NULL when this.Parent is not of the type Form1, but is another container. alternatively, if the parent is not set. to fix this, you need to get a reference of the Form to the user control or alternatively, set the parent. something like:

```
UserControl1 uc=new UserControl1();
uc.control=1;
uc.Parent = this;
```